# How to set scenes in the new Philips HUE API node-hue-api v.3

Tags: philips-hue

can anyone give a description on how to set a specific scene to a specific lamp in the new node-hue-api v.3?

For example the Scene ID would be id="shshshshsh" and the Group ID group="8"

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is an example in the github repository for the project that shows how to set a light state on a specific light as part of a scene, https://github.com/peter-murray/node-hue-api/blob/master/examples/v3/scenes/updateSceneLightState.js#L57

You mention a group in your example here though, so are you specifically referring to a GroupScene? If so the state of the lights in a GroupScene are stored in the Group itself, so you would need to modify the Group.